# How to clear bash history completely?

Tags: bash, history

I want to clear all previous commands from the history of my server. I used `history -c` and it seems all things are cleared but when I ssh to the server, all the commands are still there.

How can I clear them permanently?

Answer (score 495, accepted):

The file `~/.bash_history` holds the history.

To clear the bash history completely on the server, open terminal and type

```
cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history
```

Other alternate way is to link `~/.bash_history` to `/dev/null`

#### However,

One annoying side-effect is that the history entries has a **copy in the memory** and it will **flush back to the file when you log out**.

To workaround this, use the following command (worked for me):

```
cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history && history -c && exit
```

Comment: you can also put above command in .bashrc & .bash_logout . what it mean when you login u will have clear history & when you logout out your history will be cleared

Comment: Why do you need /dev/null there? Wouldn't `> ~/.bash_hstory` be enough?

Comment: yes it would be enough!

Comment: It seems that there exists several copies. One is for root and the others for other users. I can't find the other user's copies.

Comment: I tried to do it on a raspberry box while connected via SSH.

I added the above command ( cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history && history -c && exit )  to both .bashrc & .bash_logout as suggested by @Qasim .

Now as soon as I connect via SSH the remote host closes the connection (after printing the motd) . Help :/

Comment: Goes to show what happens when you blindly do things without reading properly and without understanding the processing and data flow. It also shows the pitfalls of bad communication. What devav2 did was run it one time, and what Qasim should have written is to remove the exit command before adding it in login script.

Comment: Also works on Mac OS X El Capitan (tested on version 10.11.2), but you have to add that following line to your `~/.bash_profile`: `export SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0`, then do a `source ~/.bash_profile` and to finish shut down and restart your Terminal app. If you want to understand what this export command does, then you should definitely check this following link: http://superuser.com/questions/950403/bash-history-not-preserved-between-terminal-sessions-on-mac

Comment: In my case the `~/.bash_profile` file only held very old command history. I had to use the `history` command to assess the recently issued commands and `history -d NNN` to delete a specific command holding sensitive information.

Comment: you can also use vim, `vim ~/.bash_history` to erase only the lines you really want to get rid of from the history and then invoke `history -c && exit` to make it persistent

Comment: It worked.  But I had to write (`cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history', new line, `history -c') to both `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_logout` for my normal user and `~/.bashrc` for root.  I like Ubuntu; I don't like this.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. What worked was the shorter solution with just issuing `history -cw` as mentioned in callpraths' answer.

Comment: Neither `cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history && history -c && exit` nor `history -c` worked for me, it says `fc: event nor found: -c`. What's going on?

Answer (score 210):

What to do:

In *every* open bash shell (you may have multiple terminals open):

```
history -c
history -w
```

Why:
As noted above, `history -c` empties the file `~/.bash_history`. It is important to note that bash shell does not immediately flush history to the bash_history file. So, it is important to (1) flush the history to the file, and (2) clear the history, *in all terminals*. That's what the commands above do.

Reference: http://www.giannistsakiris.com/index.php/2007/09/13/how-to-clear-bash-history-and-what-to-watch-out-for/

Comment: Actually, the other way around worked for me.

Comment: In many cases, you can combine these two commands together: `history -cw`

Comment: For some reason this does not work on Ubuntu 14.04, probably others. It should but it doesn't. If you issue the command "history -cw" you can confirm with the up arrow that the history isn't there anymore, but if you start another terminal window (in Unity desktop) with shift + click on the terminal icon (I have it pinned in the launcher) the commands history are back, no matters how many times you do "history -cw". "cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history" is the only way that worked for me.

Comment: While I'm not Ubantu, works fine for my bash shell in OSX.

Comment: It's history -c and then history -w, you first clear the history then write the changes. This is easily confirmed by closing the terminal and opening it again, with -w first the commands are there again, with -w last history is effectively cleared.

Comment: It doesn't clear ~/.bash_history, it clears whatever the history file is at that moment ($HISTFILE).

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me. This is much shorter and worked.

Comment: The link is dead and currently points to a potentially dangarous scam. Wayback link to be used instead: https://web.archive.org/web/20180403200605/http://www.giannistsakiris.com/2007/09/13/how-to-clear-bash-history-and-what-to-watch-out-for/ (There are too many pending edits and I can’t edit)

Answer (score 92):

execute the following commands to clear history forever

```
history -c && history -w
```

good luck!

Comment: Much better than the accepted answer. ;)

Comment: This answer would be even more helpful if it explained what these flags do (and therefore why/when they're the right commands to use).

Answer (score 19):

There's another much simpler one: running `history -c` on the terminal prompt and gone are all entries in the `bash_history` file.

Comment: No, it is not. Log out, log in, arrow-up gives me everything. You need the "history -w" too.

Comment: If you read the OP's question you would know that using `history -c` is the exact method that led to this question.

Answer (score 12):

Clear the current shell's history:

```
history -c
```

When you log out, your current shell's history is appended to ~/.bash_history, which is a cache of previous shells' histories, to a maximum number (see HISTFILESIZE in "man bash").

If you want to remove the history altogether, then you essentially have to empty out ~/.bash_history which many of the above entries have suggested.  Such as:

```
history -c && history -w
```

This clears the current shell's history and then forces the current shell's history (empty) to overwrite ~/.bash_history....or to be more accurate, it forces it to overwrite HISTFILE (which defaults to ~/.bash_history).

Hope this helps.

Comment: You answer is accurate, but the question was two years old, had accepted answers, and included the same answer you have given.

Answer (score 10):

Another way to do this is deleting the `~/.bash_history` file by using `rm ~/.bash_history` command. When you login another time, the `.bash_history` file will be automatically created.

Comment: At least on some OSes ~/.bash_history is written to disk when you log out - Not sure about *buntus.

Answer (score 8):

```
rm ~/.bash_history; history -c; logout
```

Now log back in and witness that your arrow-up doesn't give you anything.

Comment: @KasiyA It's about a server and a ssh session, so no need to edit...

Comment: Slightly modified to `rm -f ~/.bash_history; history -c; exit`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

edit your `.profile` and add the line below at the end of the file

```
rm -f .bash_history
```

this way, every time you login, it will delete your .bash_history file automatically for you. Adding the -r recursive remove option seems dangerous and not needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the history **not to be saved in the first place**, you should add this to your `~/.profile`:

```sh
unset HISTFILE
```

That's it.
All new invocations of bash (if you re-login) will not log anything. After that you can delete the old `~/.bash_history` file as well if you want.