# How do I completely clear a terminal window

Tags: command-line

The commands of `clear`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, or `reset` are not adequate. They do not clear my terminal screen, they just seem to scroll the window down so I can't see everything above.

I want it so that I can't scroll up and see any previous history.

Comment: Already answered in this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/191999/how-to-clear-bash-history-completely

Comment: Do you want to clear written commands too? I cannot understand why reset won't suit your purpose.

Comment: @GhassenRjab no, that question is about clearing the history, it won't affect the lines shown in the scrollback buffer.

Comment: Why is reset not adequate?

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using? (`ps $PPID` should tell you that.) The commands you mentioned only send messages; it's up to the particular terminal emulator to respond to those messages, and there is some variation in exactly how they're handled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you type `reset` it'll totally reinitialize your terminal instead of clearing your screen. You can setup a keyboard shortcut for that.

`printf "\033c"` also work well and takes less time.
You can alias it by `alias cls='printf "\033c"'` too. Now when you type `cls` terminal should get cleared.

For more detailed explaination take a look [at this Stack Overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367068/clear-the-ubuntu-bash-screen-for-real)

Comment: you can also do this GUI way navigating to terminal menu bar choose terminal and from there reset / reset and clear.