# How to delete bash history for specific date range

Tags: command-line, bash, history, bash-history

I know how to [delete the complete history](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191999/how-to-clear-bash-history-completely) of all the commands I have ran in my bash terminal, however, I don't want to delete all the history.

What I want is to delete the history for a specific date range.

How do I do that?

Comment: Have you already enabled timestamps for bash history?

Comment: .bash_history doesn't know about time, unless you have something in your .bashrc

Comment: @muru No, I havent.