# clear terminal cache

Tags: command-line, history, bash-history

I need to clear the terminal cache, I have tried with `history -c` but it clears the cache in that terminal session, but if I open another session and type `history` it shows all the previous commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question, with a few solutions if you are using bash as your shell. There are a few different options, depending on what you are trying to accomplish. There are some ways to clear it now, and ways to clear it on login or logout.

[How to clear bash history completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191999/how-to-clear-bash-history-completely)

Basically speaking, `history -c` clears it but you need to do a `history -w` to write the empty file to your `~/.bash_history`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this happened because you were running it from a terminal emulator, if you want to delete all your history (be wary), you can try to delete directly the file which log it:

```
rm ~/.bash_history
```